Solve for $x$: $x^2 + x = 14\log_2(\log_2(x)) + 6, \quad x > 1$
$x^2 + x = 14\log_2(\log_2(x)) + 6, \quad x > 1$
The solutions are $2$ and $4,$ but I couldn't seem to find a way to show it. I've tried substituting and reorganizing terms based on known solutions to find something well-behaved, but neither seem to work. I asked ChatGPT, but it suggested some advanced numerical methods I'm not aware of. This is a problem from a high school calculus math workbook, so there must be a relatively simple solution. I hope to receive some hints.
Thank you!

Is there a reason this was tagged "calculus"? It seems more of an algebra workout than a calculus one. Or have I missed something? (It happens a lot...)

@RedFive Hi, this is a problem from a calculus book and calculus techniques are expected, though not required. Since I wasn't able to solve it, I'm not entirely sure if calculus is not required to solve this, so I added the tag in case it's not just simple algebra manipulation.

OK thanks. I was wondering if I had missed a key detail. My first instinct was to subtract 6 from both sides and then factorise, but this hasn't gotten me very far...

It may well be that "calculus" is key here... the LHS is a concave-up function whereas the RHS is concave-down. This means there will be a maximum of two points of intersection. Finding what those points are, of course, is another matter!

@RedFive Yup. When I moved all the terms to the LHS and input the function into Desmos, the graph looked like a concave-up parabola and intersected the x-axis at 2 and 4.

Replace $x=2^{2^u}$ to achieve $4^{2^u}+2^{2^u}=14u+6$. Both $f(u)=4^{2^u}$ and $g(u)=2^{2^u}$ are convex functions w.r.t. $u$, and so is $(f+g)(u)$. Every straight line intersects with a convex function in at most two points. Since $14u+6$ has already intersected with $(f+g)(x)$ at $u=0$ (i.e. $x=2$) and $u=1$ (i.e. $x=4$), then $x=2$ and $x=4$ are the only solutions to your equation $\blacksquare$

Thank you very much!

You have $$x^2+x-6=(x+3)(x-2)=14\log_2(\log_2(x))$$
Note that you have $\log_2(\log_2(x))=0$ when $x=2$ and $\log_2(\log_2(x))=1$ when $x=4$ (i.e. when $(x+3)(x-2)=14$). These two facts give the two solutions $x=2$ and $x=4$. Besides for $x\lt2$ and $x\gt4$ we can see that $(x+3)(x-2)\gt14\log_2(\log_2(x))$.
Thus $x=2$ and $x=4$ are the only solutions.

Hi, thank you very much! On your last remark ("Besides for $x < 2$ and $x > 4$..."), is it based on the fact that the derivative of $x^2+x−6 - 14\log_2(\log_2(x)) > 0$ for $x>4$ and $<0$ for $x <2$? Essentially, I struggle to find an easier way to prove that statement, but since you didn't elaborate on that part, I was hoping there is a better way.

Let $f(x)=x^2+x-14\log_2(\log_2x)-6$
Since $f(2)=f(4)=0$ we clearly have that $x=2,4$ are the solutions of the given  equation.
So what your author actually wants you to do is that you find the roots $x=2,4$ by Hit and Trial and then prove that there exist no other solutions to the equation.
So, let us assume that $f(x)=0$ has three solutions.
By Rolle's theorem , $f'(x)=0$ will have at least two solutions and on further invoking this theorem we can say that $f''(x)=0$ will have at least one solution.
$f'(x)=2x+1-\frac{14}{(ln2)^2x\log_2x}$
$f''(x)=2+\frac{14}{(ln2)^2}\{\frac{1}{x^2\log_2x}+\frac{1}{ln2}\frac{1}{x^2(log_2x)^2}\}>0$
which is a contradiction.
So our assumption that $f(x)=0$ has three solutions is false.
So the only roots are $x=2,4$

While I accepted another answer, I really liked your approach of invoking Rolle's theorem. This seems to be a very powerful technique when it's not straightforward to solve for x using more common approaches. I'll keep this in mind. Thank you very much!
